# Access Gmail's email without imap or pop3

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I have a problem, i have developed a code to access Gmail's email via imap but most of online server don't allow opening of port 993 even on dedicated IP which is necessary for imap. I am confused,

1. How to access gmail's email without imap
2. What's online server mean when they say they support imap but don't allow to open port 993. How imap can be accessible without opening port 993.
3. Any alternate solution is appreciated.

Comment: 1. i dont believe you can. 2 ask them 3. out of luck

Comment: i have seen but not found any of google api, can you confirm

Comment: 2, they maybe allow incoming 993, so you could run an imap server.

Comment: IMAP is the external mail API.

Answer (score 0):

If your hoster blocks outgoing TCP connections to port 993, I would suggest to switch the hosting provider. There's plenty of companies which offer uncrippled service.

Answer (score -2):

Try IMap non ssl port 143.

```
imap_open( "{server.example.com:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX" , 'login' , 'password' );
```

Thanks

Comment: Gmail does not allow plain text connections at all. They only allow SSL secured connections on 993.